# Cursor Frozen During Install

Tags: gnome, nvidia, wayland, cursor, nouveau

Recently tried installing both latest ApricityOS and Fedora 25 (gnome versions). The cursor freezes in the top left corner. I can still click on things (if I guess correctly). Everything else seems to work fine. I've got an Nvida GTX1080 which I suspect is the problem. I've read that there are some issues with nouveau and the Pascal series, and issues with Wayland and Nvidia. Does anyone know how I can get either working?

Comment: You mean the mouse cursor?  Is the mouse, in fact, functional?

Comment: The mouse works fine. Tested it on another PC. The mouse arrow just stays top left, but if you move the physical mouse, things will get the mouse-over animation and you can click on things. But during this, the cursor will not move.

Comment: Other things I've tried: Different mouse. Unplugging and replugging the mouse. Multiple new install USB creations. On ApricityOS live, installing the nvidia drivers (kinda of dumb probably but I thought I'd check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and found the solution here:

```
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398764
```

To summarize:

First, you'll have to install Fedora using the keyboard. Slightly annoying, but not too hard.

Then, after you're installed and booted, run the following:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo=http://negativo17.org/repos/fedora-nvidia.repo
sudo dnf upgrade
sudo dnf install nvidia-driver nvidia-settings kernel-devel
```

Finally, restart, and you should have a mouse.